# Convert one delphi code line to c++

Tags: c++, delphi

How can I write that line in c++?

with delphi code (not this code posted here) i will write that record filled with some info to exe file and with c++ code i will read thhis record and pass the info to the struct

This is the code in delphi

```
type
 TSettings = record
    sFileName: String[50]; 
    siInstallFolder: Byte; 
    bRunFile: Boolean;
   ...
  end;

..
var
i: dword;
sZdData: PChar;
Settings :Tsettings;
begin
....
     ZeroMemory(@Settings, sizeof(Tsettings));
      settings := Tsettings(Pointer(@sZdData[i])^); // this code to c++
```

c++ code (hope the rest is OK)

```c
struct TSettings{
    char sFileName[50]; 
    byte siInstallFolder; 
    bool bRunFile;
   ...
}  Settings;

...
DWORD i;
LPBYTE sZdData;

         ZeroMemory(&Settings, sizeof(TSettings));
      Settings = ????? // im failing here i dunno what to do // i need same as in delphi code above
```

and sory for my bad english .. :(

this is the delphi code

```
function GetInfoSettings(FileName: String; // filename from where to get data
                        var lpData: PChar; // where to write data
                        var dwSettingsLen: DWORD // returns the length of all bound files
                        ): Boolean;
var
  hFile: THandle;
  DosHeader: TImageDosHeader;
  NtHeaders: TImageNtHeaders;
  SectionHeader: TImageSectionHeader;
  dwReadBytes, dwOrginalFileSize, dwFileSize, dwSettingsLength: DWORD;
begin
  Result := False;
  hFile :=  Createfile(PChar(FileName), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
  ReadFile(hFile, DosHeader, sizeof(DosHeader), dwReadBytes, nil);
  if dwReadBytes = sizeof(DosHeader) then
  begin
    SetFilePointer(hFile, DosHeader._lfanew, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
    ReadFile(hFile, NtHeaders, sizeof(NtHeaders), dwReadBytes, nil);
    if dwReadBytes = sizeof(NtHeaders) then
    begin
      SetFilePointer(hFile, sizeof(SectionHeader) * (NtHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections -1), nil, FILE_CURRENT);
      ReadFile(hFile, SectionHeader, sizeof(SectionHeader), dwReadBytes, nil);
      dwOrginalFileSize := SectionHeader.PointerToRawData + SectionHeader.SizeOfRawData;
      dwFileSize := GetFileSize(hFile, nil);
      dwSettingsLength := dwFileSize - dwOrginalFileSize;
      if dwSettingsLength > 0 then
      begin
        SetFilePointer(hFile, dwOrginalFileSize, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
        GetMem(lpData, dwSettingsLength);
        ReadFile(hFile, lpData^, dwSettingsLength, dwReadBytes, nil);
        if dwReadBytes = dwSettingsLength then
        begin
          Result := True;
          dwSettingsLen := dwSettingsLength;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  CloseHandle(hFile);
end;
```

and here i get the info or the binded file ...

var
  i, // here will be saved how much bytes are already done ..
  dwDaSize: DWORD; // length of data after all sections ..
  dwFilenaam,sFileName :string;
  sZdData: PChar; // here will be all data after "EOF" (End of all sections data)
 // the filename where the file will be extracted ..

```
  Settings: Tsettings;


// writting
  hFile: THandle;
  lpNumberOfBytesWritten: DWORD;
begin
  GetMem(dwFilenaam, MAX_PATH);
  GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle(nil), dwFilenaam, MAX_PATH);
  if GetInfos(dwFilenaam, sZdData, dwDaSize) then
  begin
    i := 0;
    repeat

      ZeroMemory(@Settings, sizeof(Tsettings));
      settings := Tsettings(Pointer(@sZdData[i])^);
```

my try (i know this code looks garbage LOL) maybe not?

```
bool getSettingsInfo(LPSTR FileName, LPBYTE lpdata, DWORD dwSettingsLen)
{
    HANDLE HandleFile ;
    DWORD  dwReadBytes;
    DWORD dwOrginalFileSize;
    DWORD dwFileSize;
    DWORD dwSettingsLength; 
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pidh ;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pinh ;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pish;

    return  false;
    HandleFile =  CreateFile(FileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0,OPEN_EXISTING,0, NULL); 
    SetFilePointer(HandleFile, 0,0, FILE_BEGIN);
        ReadFile(HandleFile, pidh, sizeof(pidh), &dwReadBytes,NULL); 
    if (dwReadBytes == sizeof(pidh))
     {
     SetFilePointer(HandleFile, pidh->e_lfanew , NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
     ReadFile(HandleFile, pidh,sizeof(pinh), &dwReadBytes, NULL); 
    if (dwReadBytes == sizeof(pinh)) 
    {
      SetFilePointer(HandleFile, sizeof(pish) * (pinh->FileHeader.NumberOfSections -1), NULL, FILE_CURRENT);
      ReadFile(HandleFile, pish, sizeof(pinh), &dwReadBytes, NULL);
      dwOrginalFileSize = pish->PointerToRawData + pish->SizeOfRawData;
      dwFileSize = GetFileSize(HandleFile, NULL);
      dwSettingsLength = dwFileSize - dwOrginalFileSize;
      if (dwSettingsLength > 0) 
      {

        SetFilePointer(HandleFile, dwOrginalFileSize, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
        realloc(lpdata, dwSettingsLength);
        ReadFile(HandleFile, lpdata, dwSettingsLength, &dwReadBytes, NULL);
        if (dwReadBytes == dwSettingsLength) 
        {
         return true;
          dwSettingsLen = dwSettingsLength;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  CloseHandle(HandleFile);
}
```

code to extract info ...

```
  DWORD i; // here will be saved how much bytes are already done ..
  DWORD dwDaSize; // length of data after all sections ..

  LPSTR dwFilenaam; 
  LPBYTE sZdData; // here will be all data after "EOF" (End of all sections data)
  LPSTR sFileName;// the filename where the file will be extracted ..

  char * Installpath;
  char * buffer;

  HFILE hFile;
  DWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten;

  memset(dwFilenaam,0, MAX_PATH);
  GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle(NULL), dwFilenaam, MAX_PATH);
  if (getSettingsInfo(dwFilenaam, sZdData, dwDaSize) == true)
  {
      i = 0;
    //  REPEAT


      ZeroMemory(&Settings, sizeof(TSettings));

Settings = ???
```

Comment: Delphi short string (String[50]) is 51 bytes in size, since sFileName[0] holds the length of the string.

Comment: You need to post some of the code you've omitted with `...`. Somewhere, content was assigned to `sZdData` with an assignment, and there's other info available in that missing code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  struct TSettings{
     uchar length ; // shortstrings have an implicit length byte
     char sFileName[50]; 
     byte siInstallFolder; 
     bool bRunFile;  // one byte, 1=true, 0=false  any other value undefined
     ...
   }  Settings;


  DWORD i;
  LPBYTE sZdData;

  ZeroMemory(&Settings, sizeof(TSettings));   

  literally it is something like
    Settings = (struct Settings)  (*((void *)&sZDData[i])

  essentially it does

  memcpy (&sZDData[i],&settings,sizeof(TSettings));
```

What it does is take the address of the i-th element of sZSdata ( @sZDDATA[i]) and cast it to an untyped pointer.  (equivalent in C++  (void*)(&sZDData[i]))   )

Then comes the funky part, derefence it (^ as postfix operator in pascal, * as prefix operator in C) (essentially the result of that being the address the (void) ptr points to, a block of memory without length data attached to it).

When that is assigned to settings, that apparantly means move as many bytes as the size of the lvalue (= sizeof(settings)) bytes from that address into the lvalue (settings).

It's a very funky construct and I'm not sure if I have seen it before. I check to both asm level in Delphi and FPC, and they behaved the same.

Comment: This isn't what the Delphi code does at all, and it's not what the C++ code should do either. There's no `memcpy` involved; it's a direct typecast of the content referenced by the pointer `sZdData` into a record. IOW, it assigns the content of a `TSettings` variable to a block of memory at `sZdData[i]`s address (creating a typed pointer to that same location). There's no `move` or `copy` involved at all; in the code posted, both `Settings` and `sZdData[i]` reference the same block of memory.

Comment: ive addes all code mybe it help you guys to understand what i need thanks for the answers guys

Comment: Note that the post said "essentially". It was meant to simplify it for the reader. In reality it is inline rep ; movsd + movsw/b statements if needed, but I don't know how to show that for C. And you description is wrong. It assigns the content of the block /TO/ the TSettings value, not the other way around. In the code I saw (before the additions), there was no way to find out what szddata points too. I assumed it was an unrelated  filebuffer.

Comment: ive posted some codes to understand everything .. so your code will do same as in delphi code above? if so thanks man bedankt :P

Comment: You're right about my mistake in wording. My comment should have said "Assigns the content of a block of memory at `sZdData[i]`s address to a `TSettings` variable". That doesn't change the fact that there is absolutely *no* move or copy involved; setting a pointer to point to the same memory as another pointer does NOT involve a copy or move. It's a simple address assignment to the pointer. :) Also note I didn't downvote; I just commented that your answer was not quite correct.

Comment: and can you help and write correct one ? and if a variable declared as string in delphi how to declared i c++? char str; ? thanks all

Comment: Ken White: ah, then we have a different argument. Data _IS_ moved, I just thought you meant it doesn't use official "move" procedures (it is inlined).  As I already said in my earlier comment, you can see the mov* assembler statements in the generated assembler source (I used D2009 and FPC 2.7.1, both reacting the same).  Semantically, it's the ^ (circonflexe) that makes the expression non pointer.

Comment: user1332636: for production code, just use the memcpy line (I hope I got it right). The other translation is how it would like if you did this in C, and is for the language purists. I don't even know if C supports constructs like this (for their sake, I hope not, since it involves dereferencing an void pointer.)

Answer (score 0):

It should be easier in C than Delphi:

```
typedef struct 
{
     uchar length ; // shortstrings have an implicit length byte
     char sFileName[50]; 
     byte siInstallFolder; 
     bool bRunFile;  // one byte, 1=true, 0=false  any other value undefined
     ...
} TSettings;

TSettings settings;
DWORD i;
LPBYTE sZdData;

settings = *(TSettings*)(&sZdData[i]);
```

This will call memcpy, not because of casting, because of assigning TSettings structure. You can access without copying if you use pointer to TSettings:

```
TSettings* pSettings;
DWORD i; 
LPBYTE sZdData;

pSettings = (TSettings*)(&sZdData[i]);
printf("%d\n", pSettings->siInstallFolder); // example
```

**By the way, be careful for alignment. Total structure size can exceed your expectation because of gaps between items.**

Comment: Btw nearly all 32/64-bit compilers will accept the equivalent of your code in Pascal too. The example is convoluted.